# Updating query a[i] = max(a[i], x) and Minimum query for intervals

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I want to know the fast algorithm to solve this simple problem:

- You are given a sequence `a[0], a[1],..., a[N - 1]`.
- You are given `Q` queries. All queries are query 1 or 2. Process all queries.

  1. You are given integers l, r, x. Update `a[i] = max(a[i], x) for l <= i <= r`.
  2. You are given integers l, r. Find `a[l] + a[l + 1] + ... + a[r]`.

I only have a naive `O(NQ)` algorithm, so please find more faster algorithm because I want to solve for `N <= 200000, Q <= 200000`.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework

Comment: @FilipAllberg I think it is contest problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be easily solved by interval tree(or segment tree) with lazy tag.If you are not familiar with interval tree,you may refer to [this](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051) article.The time complexity is **O(Q*logN)**.

Comment: can you elaborate more?